# Pool pump safety question

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci

I have a 1.5 SPL pool pump that is on 30a breaker with #10 wire to a 20a gfci plug in a water proof box. What can I do to fix this. It seems to draw a lot of watts . Is there something that I need to do to correct this. Is it safe.

Comment: What do you mean seems to draw?  Are the wires almost burn your skin when you touch them?  Is something smoking?  The pump should have a label on it saying it's wattage.  Cam get a watt meter and see if the pump is drawing more than it should.  The 20amp plug on a 30 amp breaker might be a no-no.

Comment: WhatvI meant is it seems to use a lot of power.

Comment: We need the name plate on the pool pump. What is 'SPL"?

Comment: Is it working 24 hours a day or does it cycle on and off?  Watt meters are quite inexpensive(~$20) and will let you know exactly what it is using.  Then compare to what the wattage is on the label/name tag plus a little easy math and you will if there is a problem.  Have you checked the pump recently for blockages?

Comment: How do you know it uses a lot of power? Speculation? did you take any measurements? What is the HP of the motor?    There are charts online that can estimate the power consumption based on HP.    @crip659  the motor name plate probably won't say wattage, rather it will say amps.